Wake on lan keeps disabling itself every now and then
I work mostly from home so it's not something i check often, but every now on then when i go to the office and try to wake my machine up , it won't. I wouldn't normally be too fussed about it but it's the second time when this has happened in the past year.
Anyone knows what might be disabling it and how i can prevent it in the future ?
Machine is running Windows 10 , router is Asus , the wake command leaves the router but never reaches the PC

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

the wake command leaves the router but never reaches the PC ... that makes no sense

I use my router which i access remotely to send a wake on lan command to my computer. If the Wake On Lan is enabled on the network card , it turns on , but for some reason it keeps disabling itself. What doesn't make sense ?
